# Replace plain-text properly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace, replacewith

This is Replace text [script](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/jquery.ba-replacetext.js).

I call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test-id').replaceText(/\[this\]/g,'<b>').replace(/\[\/this\]/g,'</b>');
});
```

It should make bold `[this] bold text [/this]` only,  **HTML** below:

```
<span id="test-id"> [this] This is some text that contains [/this] red color with bold text</span>
```

It should bold text only inside this `[this][/this]` , but problem is it also make bold others the text and not hide last `[/this]` one.

I also tried to call this one:

```
$('#test-id').replaceText(/\[this\]/g,'<b>');
```

So please advice how to replace only `[this] This is some text that contains [/this]`, not other text and hide last `[/this]` one.

Please see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vw5b1szm/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$('#test-id').replaceText(/\[(\/)?this\]/g, '<$1b>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/edf5z48k/)

Since you are doing dom based replacements you can't do it in 2 steps ie `[this]` and `[/this]` can't be replaced in 2 different calls instead you need to replace it in a single call to `replaceText`. Also you second replace is using `replace` not `replaceText`

Comment: Hi, Arun one more thing is, when <span id="test-id"> [this] This is <i>some</i> text  [/this] </span> Then it's not working, please help.

Comment: that is a problem with the plugin... it does not support text with dom elements in it to be replaced

Comment: What is the line in this plugin we should Change, there any advice please.